# Android Как отследить закрытие фрагмента внутри активити

Tags: android

У меня есть активити, внутри него у меня фрагмент. На фрагменте находится кнопка закрытия, которая закрывает фрагмент

`fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit()`

Так вот, на фрагменте есть поля из которых я хочу вытянуть значения после закрытия. Можно ли как-то отследить закрытие фрагмента внутри активити? Фрагмент запускаю так:

```
fragmentManager!!.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, Fragment1())
            .commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну у вас есть жизненный цикл фрагмента. Вы можете создать какой-то интерфейс вроде такого:

```
interface ActivityInterractor {

    fun onFragmentClosed()
}
```

Реализовать этот интерфейс в `Activity`:

```
class Activity : AppCompatActivity(), ActivityInterractor {

    override fun onFragmentClosed() {
        // здесь вы можете выполнять нужные вам действия по закрытию фрагмента
    }
}
```

Во фрагменте создать экземпляр этого интерфейса и присвоить ему значение:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is ActivityInterractor) {
        this.activityInterractor = context
    }
}
```

И где-нибудь в методе `onDestroyView()` вызывать:

```
activityInterractor.onFragmentClosed()
```